# JQuery CSS selector syntax error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

At this point time I'm assuming jQuery uses exactly the same format as CSS does when using CSS selectors.

However, I have the following line in my JS (with a log to try and find the problem)

```
boxheight = $('.item .active > .html-carousel-slide > .slide-content-box').height();
    console.log(boxheight);
```

Now when I view the console log it just says Null, I'm assuming that it did not select properly and thus the variable was never initialized in the first place so remained at Null.

Am I selecting the element wrong? Definitely the correct hierarchy.

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/v750dsL5/
What is the HTML you are having trouble with?

Comment: @person66 I'm basically creating a function that changes the top property of a box to (slider it is in's height - (boxes height /2)) in order to have a constant vertical center of the box.

Here is my HTML for the slide http://pastebin.com/7edC1hef

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question please

Comment: @FelipeWarrener Your selector syntax is wrong, you don't want a space between item and active, you want `.item.active > ...`. If you use `.item .active` (with the space) then you are selecting `.active` that is a descendant of `.item`

Comment: `.item .active` should be `.item.active` (no space) since your div is both `.item` and `.active`

Comment: Thanks guys, jogged my CSS memory there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the element `<div class="item active">` in your HTML and are trying to select it with `.item .active` which is incorrect. Use `.item.active` instead. The space between the classes says select all elements that have the class `active` that are descendants of all elements with the class `item`. What you really wanted to say was select the elements that have **both** the item and active classes, which you do by removing the space between the two.